# How to load css on UIWebview in tvOS app built using swift(SpriteKit)?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, tvos, apple-tv

I am creating `tvOS` app using `spriteKit` and unable to load `css` on `UIWebview`.

Comment: UIWebview is unavailable in tvOS. How do you use it?

Comment: let webViewClass : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
let webViewObject : NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webview.loadRequest(request)
let uiview = webview as! UIView
uiview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
view.addSubview(uiview)

Comment: UIWebView is present on the apple TV, but it's PROHIBITED to use it, so, the only real way of loading web apps on an apple TV is creating them with TVML and TVJS..But for now I have used like above.

Comment: And how do you try to load css? Provide more code please.

Answer (score 2):

Let my html including CSS is -

```html
let myHTML = "<html>"+"<head>"+"<style type=\"text/css\">"+"@font-face{font-family: myFirstFontB;src: url('\(fontPath)')}"+"</style>"+"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styleIPAD.css' /></head>"+"<body>"+"<div class='page'>\(value)</div>"+"</body>"+"</html>"
```

Here styleIPAD.css is located in my project.

Now you can load this html string to your uiwebview -

webview?.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)

Please give the bundle url, else CSS will not load.